# How do I distinguish between two imports with the same name in as3?

Tags: actionscript-3, import, disambiguation

I have two `ArrayUtil` classes I need to access from the same class - they each come from external libraries and have different code, so I can't just combine them.

How do I disambiguate them in the code?

I tried doing `com.adobe.utils.ArrayUtil` inline, and leaving the existing import, but that resulted in an `undefined property com` error.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
// In main class/timeline etc

import package1.*;
import package2.*;

var a1:package1.A = new package1.A();
var a2:package2.A = new package2.A();
```

Package 1 Class

```
// In package1.A.as
package package1 {

    public class A {

        public function A() {
            // constructor code
            trace("P1");
        }

    }

}
```

Package 2 Class

```
// In package2.A.as
package package2 {

    public class A {

        public function A() {
            // constructor code
            trace("P2");
        }

    }

}
```

Output

```
// Outputs
P1
P2
```

If you need to access static methods or properties. You would do something similar to the following:

```
import com.adobe.utils.ArrayUtil;

var a:Array = ["A", "B", "C"];
trace(com.adobe.utils.ArrayUtil.arrayContainsValue(a, "B")); // outputs true
```

Comment: Is there a similar method to access static methods? (ie `if (!com.adobe.utils.ArrayUtil.arrayContainsValue(monthNames, "total"))`)

Comment: (That line I just posted is what I tried, and it gives me an error)

Comment: Ah, I missed the 2nd import, so disambiguating didn't mean anything to the class. Thanks!

Comment: I just updated my answer as you posted your last comment to clarify around imports and static methods or properties. I hope the answer helped, and goodluck with your project

Answer (score 1):

What are the names of the libraries? Try just mx.adobe.utils.ArrayUtil for the reference to the first class.

You can most likely use the package names to reference them directly (i.e. com.domandtom.MyUtils (open it up, and you'll see it defined at the top of the class file).

Comment: I tried this, and I just get an error saying 'undefined property com' (I'm trying to reference `com.adobe.utils.ArrayUtil.arrayContainsValue()` )

Comment: I don't know what your folder structure is. In your package "com" folder, do you have the com.adobe library? Looks like you got help though

Comment: Thanks Dominic. It turns out I'd missed the import.